# three.js lambert material color not showing

Tags: javascript, three.js

i created an arrow with my own vertices and indices then i set lambert material and material color to red. i can't see material color at the render. just black.

however if i set material to basic material i can see the color.

```
arrowMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    arrowGeometry,
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color : 'red', side: THREE.DoubleSide })
);
arrowMesh.position.set(-10,5,95);
arrowMesh.rotation.x = -1.0;

arrowMesh.rotation.z = -0.2;
scene.add(arrowMesh);
```

three.js r64

Comment: Does the color show red if the geometry is `THREE.CubeGeometry`?

Comment: geometry is not THREE.CubeGeometry it is THREE.Geometry.

Comment: Please replace your `arrowGeometry` with `THREE.CubeGeometry` and answer my original question.

Comment: it didn't worked. still black and my arrow shape broked.

Comment: i tried to change color of every face with arrowMesh.geometry.faces[i].color.set(0x00ffff); in a for loop and it didn't worked too.

Comment: and i have 2 directional light on the scene.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, when using `THREE.LambertMaterial` you need some lights in your scene.

If you do have lights in your scene and you created the geometry yourself by creating vertices and faces the problem lies most likely in the fact that your face normals are set to `Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );`

Caculate and set your face normals and they should render correctly.

So for a single triangle it would look like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices = [ a, b, c ];

var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 );

face.normal = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(
    new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( b, a ),
    new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( c, b )
).normalize();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000, side: 2, shading: THREE.FlatShading}));
```

Instead of doing this manually you can also use the geometry methods for calculating them:

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem on my machine, and found that PointLight was the culprit.  Setting "distance" to zero (or leaving it at the default) caused the light to turn off completely.  Explicitly setting the distance to a large number turned on the light, and then all my Lambert materials appeared normally.

So, instead of

```
pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
```

I used

```
pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 100000);
```

And all was fixed. As far as I can tell so far, this problem is limited to PointLight, and is machine-dependent (GPU or GPU drivers, not sure exactly which).  But it's easy enough to throw a big number in there and avoid the problem.

Comment: That should not happen. What revision of three.js are you using?

Comment: Version 71 I believe.

Comment: If you can demonstrate a three.js bug as you have described, it would be helpful if you'd report it. See "How to report a bug" in the [guidelines](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: I will try to do so next week.  By the way, I will note that even the demo at the top of the documentation page for MeshLambertMaterial shows up black for me.

Comment: You mean [this](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshLambertMaterial)?

Comment: Yes.  On my machine that is black.

Comment: Yikes! If you file a three.js bug report, that would be helpful.

Comment: I've seen this occur on a couple of Windows machines too with v71. Have been trying to debug the Lambert Shader, can supply specs and more details when I have a moment.

Answer (score -2):

i solved my problem like this.

```
var ground_texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/grass.png', {}, function() {
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
});
ground_material = Physijs.createMaterial(
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map : ground_texture}),
    .9, // high friction
    .9 // low friction
);
```

i found this solution on this site.

Comment: How is this an answer to the original question?